# swagger-codegen in flutter project

Tags: flutter, swagger, flutter-http

I am new to flutter and trying to integration below library for using Swagger in flutter project.
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/dart/swagger

Steps which i did so far :

1)

```
added the Path in Pubspec.yaml
     swagger:
        path: /path/swagger-codegen-master/samples/client/petstore/dart/swagger
```

2) main.dart file :

```
import 'package:swagger/api.dart';
```

3) added in Pubspec.yaml for swagger file so my project support SDK 2.0.0

```
 environment:
      sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
```

It is working fine Problem is : 
I can able to access     var api_instance = new PetApi();
Which is swagger api implemented in that.
How can i use the url of my swagger api which had complete different API as per my project.
For eg on url `http://petstore.swagger.io/v2` but on `http://student.swagger.io/v2`
and have complete different request , header and response parameters ? 
How can i customise it as per my use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps I followed to link the swagger API files,

1.Generated the client files for dart using https://editor.swagger.io

2.Replaced the `api_client.dart` file's usage of `BrowserClient()` with `IOClient()` and imported the required library. This BrowserClient caused a build error in my project because it contains web dependencies

```
  class ApiClient {
      String basePath;
      var client = new BrowserClient();//old one
      var client = new IOClient();//should be changed to this

.
.
```

3.Then Created the client class to access the API's as below,

```
/// Singleton class for ApiClient
class Client {
  ApiClient apiClient;
  AuthApi _authApi;

  AuthApi get authApi => _authApi;
  static final Client _client = Client._initClient();

  factory Client() {
    return _client;
  }

  Client._initClient() {
    apiClient = ApiClient(
      basePath: "http://yourproject.apilink",
    );
    _authApi = AuthApi(apiClient);
  }
}
```

4.Then,

```
class AuthImpl {
  final Client client;

  AuthImpl(this.client) {}

  Future<User> signIn({
    @required String deviceID,
    @required String deviceType,
    @required String phone,
    @required String password,
  }) async {
    AuthLoginResponse authLoginResponse;
    User user;

    authLoginResponse = await client.authApi
        .authPostLogin(deviceID, deviceType, phone, password);
    user = authLoginResponse.payload;
    return user;
  }}
```